# Android Auto error : Action strip for this template must be set

Tags: kotlin, android-auto, android-automotive

I've been playing around with Android Auto recently and I am currently trying to make a navigation app using the Navigation Template provided in the android for cars library. I'm trying to utilize this template under the NavigationScreen class, but I'm getting the following error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action strip for this template must be set
...
        at com.smartherd.mynavapp.NavigationScreen.onGetTemplate(MyNavigationCarAppService.kt:37)
...
```

Here's the navigation app service code:

```kotlin
package com.smartherd.mynavapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.car.app.CarAppService
import androidx.car.app.CarContext
import androidx.car.app.Screen
import androidx.car.app.Session
import androidx.car.app.model.Action
import androidx.car.app.model.ActionStrip
import androidx.car.app.model.CarIcon
import androidx.car.app.model.Template
import androidx.car.app.navigation.model.NavigationTemplate
import androidx.car.app.validation.HostValidator


class MyNavigationCarAppService : CarAppService() {
    override fun createHostValidator(): HostValidator {
        return HostValidator.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTS_VALIDATOR
    }

    override fun onCreateSession(): Session {
        return NavigatorSession()
    }
}

class NavigatorSession() : Session() {
    override fun onCreateScreen(intent: Intent): Screen {
        return NavigationScreen(carContext)
    }
}

class NavigationScreen(carContext: CarContext) : Screen(carContext) {
    override fun onGetTemplate(): Template {
        val panAction: Action = Action.Builder(Action.PAN).setIcon(CarIcon.APP_ICON).build()
        val mapActionStrip = ActionStrip.Builder().addAction(panAction).build()
        val builder = NavigationTemplate.Builder()
        return builder.setMapActionStrip(mapActionStrip).build()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you need to set up the Action Strip using:

```
builder.setActionStrip(...)
```

Pretty much the same you are doing right now for `setMapActionStrip`